# Adding a class to a post in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I've got the following Jekyll index

```
---
layout: default
title: My favourite sandwiches
---

<section class="home">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
    <article class="column">
      <img src="{{ post.image }}">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

My site will have 3 articles (blocks) next to each other, like tiles.

However, I would like to add a class on the first and third article tag so I can add different styling.

I wanted to know how to add this behaviour and if there is a way to index something eg. `class="first" if index == 3/1`

The html I wanted is to look something like this

```
<section class="home">
    <article class="column first">
      <img src="images/bigsandwich.jpg">
      <a href="site.com/post/bigsandwich.html">My big sandwich</a>
    </article>

    <article class="column">
      <img src="images/icecreamsandwich.jpg">
      <a href="site.com/post/bigsandwich.html">Icecream sandwich</a>
    </article>

    <article class="column last">
      <img src="images/sushisandwich.jpg">
      <a href="site.com/post/sushisandwich.html">Sushi sandwich</a>
    </article>
</section>
```

Thanks you for your patience and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Liquid's for loops have helper variables available, like `forloop.first` and `forloop.last`. See documentation [here](http://wiki.shopify.com/Liquid#For_loops).

In your case, I would try:

```
---
layout: default
title: My favourite sandwiches
---

<section class="home">
  {% for post in site.posts %}

    {% if forloop.first %}
      <article class="column first">
    {% elsif forloop.last %}
      <article class="column last">
    {% else %}  
      <article class="column">
    {% endif %}

      <img src="{{ post.image }}">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </article>
  {% endfor %}
</section>
```

Comment: First, thank you. Second, thank you for your concise explanation and attribution to the documentation! I owe you a sandwich.

Comment: @WasabiDeveloper: Glad it helped. Yeah, I'd love to have the big sandwich, the first one in the loop. Lol.